# How to create a command to write partial derivatives

Tags: keycommand, renewcommand

Now I am writing a theorem in my partial differential equation course and it involves so many partial derivatives like `$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial x},\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$` and so on. Now each time I have to write the `\frac` and `\partial` command which leads to so many errors. So I was thinking may be if we define a new command like `\frac` and just write dependent and independent variables in `{ }` to get the partial derivative. So is there a way to do it?

Comment: Somehting like `\newcommand\partialder[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}` to type `\partialder{f}{u}` instead of `\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}`?

Comment: @projetmbc thank you it worked

Answer (score 1):

I use the [esdiff](http://ctan.org/pkg/esdiff) package. You can then use the `\diffp` command:

```
\diffp{f}{u} \diffp{u}{x} \diff{v}{y}
```